# Background Playlist Youtube Videos

Tags: html, video, background, youtube

I want to create a playlist background videos from youtube, i have this

HTML

```
<div id="video">   <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Fhy6CHZ9dvY?list=PL82A0C437FEE5F6DA?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;hd=1" www.youtube.com="" embed="" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1000;
```

This code works for one video and stop when  the video finish, i want to know any way to play a video after finish the first one automatically, like a playlist.

I tried embeding the playlist from youtube but isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `&amp;` instead of `?` right after the `list=PL82A0C437FEE5F6DA`.
So the final code should looks like this-

```
<div id="video">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Fhy6CHZ9dvY?list=PL82A0C437FEE5F6DA&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;hd=1" www.youtube.com="" embed="" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```